# Discord bot going offline despite being pinged

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

I created discord bot and decided to host it on Replit. I used uptimerobot to ping site every 5 mins so it does not stop after hour as it is said in replit docs. It worked for 2 weeks, i was adding few things and everything was alright until one day i noticed the bot is offline. I checked uptimerobot, there was no downtime and it was still pinging.

This is code creating web server:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "I'm alive"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)


def keep_alive():  
    t = Thread(target=run)

    t.start()
```

Main function starting bot:

```
async def main():
    async with client:          
    await load()
    keep_alive()
    TOKEN = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")
    await client.start(str(TOKEN))

asyncio.run(main())
```

I have it run inside main function, I don't think it is where problem lies but it might be significant

I was looking for solution on internet but only thing I could find was to use uptimerobot or other ways of pinging it. Bot is going offline after around one hour from leaving site. It looks as if it is insensitive for pings. However when I am on site I get response in console as usual `"IP" - - [28/Mar/2023 12:58:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`. I also thought that maybe my bot overuses CPU or RAM and what I noticed is sometimes CPU jumps to 100% of use. My bot isn't complex so I don't think it is a problem as I haven't changed it much from moment where it was working and online.

I have no idea what could've happened.

Comment: You shouldn't abuse replit's service to run bots. You'll get dozens of issues that you can't do anything about. Just get an actual VPS.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally post this as a comment, however stack isn't letting me, for some reason even though I meet the reputation requirements...

Anyways DO NOT HOST BOTS ON REPLIT.
Replit uses shared IP addresses, which can do multiple things:

- Get Ratelimited
- Bot constantly going offline due to banned IP addresses

etc.

I believe you have also followed a tutorial on how to host a discord bot for free, which no longer works.

(Replit has fixed using flask and uptimerobot to keep a repl online.)

If you are looking for free hosting alternetives, I would suggest Oracle Cloud.
You can follow this guide here: https://k21academy.com/1z0-932/how-to-create-always-free-services-in-oracle-cloud/

Cheers, Eric